# Need to register every content into the iTunes?

Tags: ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am trying to sale virtual goods on iphone app after the payment is done , the content will be downloaded from my server.Here i am having the below concerns

> [itunes] A product is any feature that you want to sell in your
>   application’s store. Products are associated with the App Store
>   through iTunes Connect

--Do i need to register every content ( each individual song - product id) into the iTunes

Why i am asking this question means, the content in the web server gets updated daily, so do i need to register every new songs added into the webserver

Pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use in-app purchase you must register every product.
It's forbidden by Apple to sell content in the app using some other pay systems (not for real world goods, as I suggest).
Another problem is limited number of in-app IDs in your itunes connect account and time of validation for product.
But you can make something like subscription to you website and give all songs or some of them only for subscibed users. Maybe it's not the best solution, but it will be approved by Apple.